# change event on compute of a List

Tags: canjs, canjs-list

I have a Map like so:

```
var AppState = can.Map.extend({
  sites: null
});
appstate = new AppState();
```

the list gets populated like this:

```
Site.findAll({}, function(sites) {
  appstate.attr('sites', sites);
});
```

which I pass to a control like this:

```
new SummaryCtrl("#summaryCtrl", {sites:appstate.compute('sites')});
```

The control looks like this:

```
var SummaryCtrl = can.Control.extend({
  '{sites} change': function(ev, type, sites) { //this doesn't fire
    var recent = sites.slice(0,25);
    var siteCount = sites.length;
    this.element.html(can.view('summaryTpl', {siteCount:siteCount, recent:recent}));
  }
});
```

Then I do this:

```
var newsite = {blah1:'blahblah', blah2:'blahblah'};
appstate.sites.unshift(newsite);
```

But the '{sites} change' function doesn't fire.  Any idea why?  Thanks!

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle, the sitecount should be 2, not 1: http://jsfiddle.net/c7tdma5k/6/

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution - not sure if its the best solution, but its ok for my use.

I realized a compute of a list does not have the same interface as the list.  Intuitively, I thought it would.  So instead of passing a compute of the list to a control, just pass the list itself and use .replace and .unshift on the list as needed.

If you need to use a map, that is fine, but again, don't pass in computes of the properties on the map, just reference the property itself and initialize as an empty list like so:

```
var State = can.Map.extend({
  sites: new can.List()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7tdma5k/25/

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because the compute only changes when the `sites` property changes, not the individual items in sites.

If you created the compute like:

`var sites = can.compute(function(){
  var sites = appState.attr("sites");
  sites.attr("length")
  return new List().replace(sites)
})`

This would work.  The compute would change anytime an item was inserted or removed in the list.  However, your answer is a better way of doing this.